# How can I display a timer counting for 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I have this Javascript code in my website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function startTimer() {
              setInterval(displayNextImage, 10000);
          }

          var images = [], x = -1;
          images[0] = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radar000116.Gif";
          images[1] = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radarClosed.gif";
      </script>
   </head>

   <body onload = "startTimer()">
       <img id="img" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radar000005.Gif">
       <button onclick="displayPreviousImage()">Previous</button>
       <button onclick="displayNextImage()">Next</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want above each image to show the timer counting the seconds to 10 in this format 00:00
The first 00 for minutes and the second 00 for seconds.

In this case there is only seconds but I want to show 00:00 and only the right 00 will be counting since it's only seconds now.

And every 10 seconds the timer will reset and the shown image will change.

Comment: What does this timer refers to?
Give more details please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok then, try using this code it will help you :

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var counter = 0;

setInterval(function () {
if (counter<10)
++counter;
else counter =0;
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="00:"+counter;
}, 1000);
```

**HTML:**

```
<p id="count"></p>
```

You can test it [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/t8ufekpx/1/).

***Edit:***

And to make it fit your question try to use this function:

```
function swap(one, two) {
document.getElementById(one).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById(two).style.display = 'none';
}
```

And your code will be:

```
setInterval(function () {
if (counter<10){
    ++counter;
} else {
    counter =0;
    swap(one,two);
}
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="00:"+counter;
}, 1000);
```

And "one" and "two" here are the ids of your imgages tags.